# Delete the character sequence \r\n on linux using tr/sed etc

Tags: linux, shell, sed, tr

I am trying to delete the string `'\r\n'` from a file.

Using `sed`:

```
cat foo | sed -e 's/\015\012//'
```

does not seem to work.

```
tr -d '\015'
```

will delete a single character but I want to remove the string `\015\012`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `\r\n` like return\newline, or do you have the character `\r\n`.  Give example text before and after.

Comment: you want to put a full text fill from Windows/Dos format to 1 line ? or convert to a unix text file (leaving newline) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can offer a perl solution:

```
$ printf "a\nb\r\nc\nd\r\ne\n" | perl -0777 -pe 's/\r\n//g' | od -c
0000000   a  \n   b   c  \n   d   e  \n
0000010
```

The `-0777` option causes the entire file to be slurped in as a single string.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\|\n//g'
```

This is to remove any `\r` and `\n` characters. If you want the sequence `\r\n`, then use this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n//g'
```

tuned from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/520567